# Javascript that gets current url and changes page appearance

Tags: javascript

I need JS code that does the following

1.) Get's the current url of the page.

2.) If url = a certain url 
        Then = #header is set to display:none;

3.) If else = no change

Came up with a few ideas with no avail, struggling with this; appreciative of any and all help.

Comment: use `window.location.url`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
document.getElementById("header").style.display = 
   window.location.url == 'certain url' ? "none" : "block";
```

OR use `IF` condition

```
if(window.location.url == 'certain url'){
    document.getElementById("header").style.display = 'none';
}else{
    document.getElementById("header").style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.location.url == 'link here'){
    document.getElementById('header').style.display='none'
else{
    document.getElementById('header').style.display='block'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the URL of the current page use document.URL in your javascript.
You can hide the header using $('#header').hide() or document.getElementById('header').style.display = "none" if the url comparison evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.URL == 'URL'){
document.getElementById("header").style.display="none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
if(window.location.href == 'someurl')
    document.getElementById('header').style.display='none'
```